# How can I import a vector drawing into Google Slides?

Tags: vector, google

Google Slides adds an annoying amount of compression on my imported images. I want to avoid compression so I want to upload my schematics in a vector format. I can basically export to any vector format possible.

How do I do this in Google Slides?

Comment: I can't get any vector formats to work - tried SVG, and EMF, but Sheets only seems to only support png, gif, and jpeg.  Try exporting your graphic as a PNG, and use that.  PNGs are lossless, so compression shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: .PNG doesn't seem to look any better unfortunately :(

Comment: I just noticed a mistake. I confused Slides with Sheets, I'm talking about Google Slides. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Apparently you can import a emf to google draw and then move that to  Slides

Comment: @joojaa I just tried that, Google Graw doesn't seem to support EMFs either, sadly. However I notice that LibreOffice Impress, which is similar to Google Slides/MS Powerpoint does support import of SVGs.  Since it's free, it might be a solution to the OPs problem.

Comment: @GerlofLeuhof - can't get it to work in Slides either.  Perhaps try LibreOffice Impress instead. It supports SVGs, and LibreOffice is free.

Comment: @Billy thanks for the insights, unfortunately that is not an option since our business is required to use Google Slides. Thank you anyway for this option

Comment: Really shame that google does not support vectors in its apps.. Just because of this I am thinking to migrate to Microsoft slides.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin I want to upvote your comment for the first sentence... but then downvote it for the second.

Comment: @Michael, na well, we cannot deny that MS slides are better :), at least IMHO, and for my use cases.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This method works flawlessly for me.

1. Upload your images/icons to Google Drive
2. Open it with CloudConvert

   - Choose export format : vector / emf.
   - Make sure that you have the checkbox to save the converted file to your Google Drive
     [image]
   - Click on button Start conversion.
3. Open emf file with Google Drawing
4. Copy/paste SVG icon into your Slides.

   - you can modify the colors as you wish, add or remove shapes

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Are you sure it's not pasted as a bitmap? Even when more complex schematics with a font are pasted?

Comment: @GerlofLeuhof Yep, when pasted there was a black circle behind the + and I was able to select it and delete it.

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed and useful technique. Embarrassing that Google Slides still doesn't natively support SVGs in 2019, but at least there is this workaround.

Comment: This trick does not seem to work anymore ...

Comment: The method works flawlessly, I just did it. Make sure you login to your google drive account in https://cloudconvert.com/svg-to-emf
As soon as the file is ready, click on "Show File" and in the GDrive preview window choose Google Drive. Presto.

Comment: These are three ways that do **not** work: 1. Add the vector graphic (in my case, an SVG) to a LibreOffice presentation, save as `.odp`, and use the "Import slides" feature of Google Slides to import it. The graphic is vectorized in LibreOffice, but will be converted to a pixel graphic on importing it to Google Slides.

Comment: 2. Convert the vector graphic to an EMF file (in the case of an SVG, this can be done with Inkscape, either using the GUI or by calling `inkscape --file inputfile.svg --export-emf outputfile.emf`) and upload it to Google Drive. When opening it in Google Drive, there is no option to open it in Google Drawing, only to convert it with CloudConvert.

Comment: 3. Convert the vector graphic using CloudConvert, download it and reupload it to Google Drive. Inspecting the downloaded file, CloudConvert also uses Inkscape to convert the file. However, Google Drive only provides the option to open it with Google Drawing for a file that was placed in your drive by CloudConvert!

Comment: Does not work, google drawing does not allow me to opem emf file.

Comment: @f0k  Seriously?  WTF, why would it restrict it that way?

Comment: This mostly worked for me, but slightly modified the image from the SVG I started out with. The image was a plot with dashed lines, but after conversion, it had solid lines.

Comment: As of october 23 the emf files have to be converted to the correct mime type first (application/x-msmetafile). Here's a sample apps script to do it: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GuARFGTqiIBcMpAEI3K_SuT1UiLwMxjHOwVm88yNMeY/edit or use https://github.com/johndifini/gdrive-uploader

Answer (score 9):

As of Apr 4th 2020, I just found an easier offline solution for this issue, especially if you have the shape already in PowerPoint.

1. Just copy the shape(s) to a new PowerPoint presentation and save it as a .ppt file.
2. Upload it to Drive. The uploaded file will open in Slides and the shape(s) will maintain their vector properties.
3. Copy the shapes from the new Slides document into the one you were working on.

Comment: This method would have worked fine back in 2018 in fac it would have worked earlier too.

Comment: As of June 2021, this is the only method worked for me. SVG/EMF/WMF all failed due to "Unsupported image format".

Comment: Does this method only work with .ppt and not .pptx? .pptx seems to have rasterized the vector in Slides.

Answer (score 2):

As of Nov 25th 2020, I just tried the old way to open a .ppt with Google slides and the .SVG will become a .jpge in Google slides.
Somehow I cannot convert .svg into smart shapes in PowerPoint, and that's why it won't work in google slides.

I find another way, which is to upload the target SVG file to Google Drive, as a regular file.
Install "CloudConvert" into Google Drive, and give it permission to read all your documents (scary! Click on the SVG file, and right-click to send to CloudConvert.
Convert to "EMF" format and (this is crucial) save back to Google Drive, and open EMF to Google Drawings. And select the target in Google Drawing and copy it into Google Slides.

I think for now this is the only way to insert svg into Google slides.

Comment: Is 2022 and to be honest, I would be embarrassed to work for the team that does the slides. Not supporting the safe and standard SVG is mindblowing.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2023 nothing of this works.
If you can create a PPTX file, you can put your SVGs inside and open it with Google Slides. Then copy-paste the images in your own presentation.

I used FreeOffice, Libreoffice file didn't work.

**UPDATE 2024**

I've found [this solution](https://support.google.com/drive/thread/238604312?hl=en&msgid=238716236) by Avi Megiddo.

Essentially, since 2023 there is a problem in Google EMF import algorithm. It is a Google script to convert EMF files to the correct MIME type. After convertion, files can be opened by Google Drawing and copied to Slides as vectors.

The script converts Google Drive last week EMFs. Copy below.

```
function betterConvertMIMETypeOfEMFs() {
  var oneWeekAgo = new Date();
  oneWeekAgo.setDate(oneWeekAgo.getDate() - 7);

  var targetMimeType = 'image/emf';
  var desiredMimeType = 'application/x-msmetafile';
  var query = 'mimeType != "' + desiredMimeType + '" and fileExtension = "emf" and modifiedDate > "' + oneWeekAgo.toISOString() + '"';
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(query);

  var count = 0;
  var maxFilesToConvert = 10;

  while (files.hasNext() && count < maxFilesToConvert) {
    var file = files.next();

    // Check if file has parents before attempting to retrieve
    var parents = file.getParents();
    if (parents.hasNext()) {
      var folder = parents.next();
 
      // Try to get the blob and change MIME type; if error, skip this file
      try {
        var blob = file.getBlob();
        blob.setContentType(desiredMimeType);
        folder.createFile(blob);
        count++;
      } catch (e) {
        Logger.log("Error processing file " + file.getName() + ": " + e.toString());
        continue;  // Skip this file and move to the next one
      }
    }
  }

  if (count === 0) {
    Logger.log('No recent EMF files needing conversion were found.');
  } else {
    Logger.log(count + ' recent EMF files converted to desired MIME type.');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to contribute!

Comment: Tried with Powerpoint and FreeOffice, it looks like it works, but it doesn't really, it converts to raster/bitmap. FreeOffice just looks like it does a better job as it has a super high resolution, but if you keep increasing the size of the images, you can see the pixels

Answer (score 0):

1. Download inkscape
2. Convert the `svg` to a `png`: `inkscape in.svg --export-type=png -o out.png -h HEIGHT -w WIDTH`
3. Drag and drop the png into the slide

Note: I have only tested the command provided on linux, not sure about Windows or other Unix based OS

Comment: png is not a vector format.

Comment: @KonradHöffner Most of the times I just needed the svg to be imported into slides, mainly icons. You can set the width and height of the png to a crazy amount and scale it down in google slides, with no noticeable loss in resolution unlike those online svg2png converters, which dont allow you set a height resulting in a very noticeable resolution drop off. If you really want an SVG I am sure you can follow the other answers, albeit with more hassle