# Import vector graphics into Google Slides? (Previous process broken)

Tags: vector, google

I'm looking for a new process to insert vector graphics into Google Slides.

Before Google cut the support (in early 2023) for the connections between Google Drive, Google Slides and Google Draw, I could create vector graphics (in Adobe Illustrator), convert those graphics using CloudConvert into EMF or WMF, download them directly to Google Drive and open them in Google Draw. This allowed me to copy/paste the editable graphics from Draw into Slides (and have the graphic be editable in Slides).

**This process is no longer viable.** Does anyone yet have a workaround? The image compression in Google slides is TERRIBLE.

(the process I discuss above, and have been utilizing until just recently is indicated in this StackExchange post: [How can I import a vector drawing into Google Slides?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/115814/how-can-i-import-a-vector-drawing-into-google-slides))

Comment: Never used Google Slides.. I'd *suspect* that for *vectors*, SVG would be the preferred Google format when pasting - since it is web-based technology. EMF/WMF are really Microsoft-specific formats for the most part.

Comment: @Scott - sadly, Slides doesn't seem to support SVG directly, unless I'm missing something, it can't even see an SVG uploaded into Google Drive, so you can't even select it.

Comment: @BillyKerr - Interesting. I was just assuming... I assumed the XML nature would be favorable for Google stuff. Not terribly surprised I'm wrong though. `:)`. I really don't use Google-anything other than search.

Comment: @Scott - yeah I'd have thought so too, seems like such an obvious choice for anything running in a web browser, but apparently not.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit off-topic since Google Slides isn't really graphic design software, but it is kind of design related, because it's about using vector graphics. So  . . .

A possible solution/workaround is to use LibreOffice Presentation (it's free) as a kind of go-between application. It's part of the LibreOffice suite. Obviously, this is assuming you have access to a Windows/Mac/Linux computer.

1. Create a new document in LibreOffice Presentation, and click and drag an SVG vector file into it.  There's no need to use EMFs/WMFs, or use any conversion. The software supports SVGs directly. In fact you could save time by putting all the vector graphics you need right inside this one document.
2. Now, save it as a .ppt document, and upload this to your Google Drive, and open it with Google Slides.
3. You can then copy and paste the SVG graphic from the uploaded .ppt document into your own Slides document.

I tested this and it seems to work. Here's an SVG I created in Inkscape (you could also use Illustrator), and which I got into Google Slides by using the method described above.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. For anyone that stumbles across this- the only way this worked for me was to right click the images and convert to curve before saving the PPT.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround that works for me is to have [Google Drive downloaded to your desktop](https://www.google.com/drive/download/).

Then use CloudConvert as usual, but when downloading WMF file, save it directly to the desired Google Drive folder from your desktop.
(*So far only WMF seems to work, when trying to open with Google Drawings.*)

Comment: This is the only way that worked for me as of Jan 2024